# How to achieve higher BGE frametime?

Tags: game-engine

When I hit <kbd>P</kbd>, my game starts usually. I have "Show Framerate and Profile" ticked, and when I play, it seems that there is a cap at 60 for my frames. How can I increase this? Also, it reads the following: `Frametime  :  00.0ms (00.0fps)`. What is the "00.0ms"? Mine does not display 0, thats just for explanation, but I am quite confused on what it means. To summarize, how can I increase the fps cap and what does the "00.0ms" area mean?

Comment: "Frametime" shows the framerate in frames per second (FPS), and milliseconds per frame (ms). At 60 FPS each frame lasts `1000/60` = `16.6666...` milliseconds. I thought disabling *Use Framerate* in *Properties > Render > System* or increasing *Properties > World > Physics > FPS* would the framerates to exceed 60, however this doesn't seem to be the case (you can limit the framerate to below 60 though)

Comment: This is the correct answer. But you might also have to disable V-Sync in the render panel. (and maybe in the display driver level as well)

Comment: For reference, frame time is how long it took to render a frame. You normally want that number to be a as low as possible. You want high frameRate, low frameTime. These two value are linked. (1/frametime = framerate)

Answer (score 1):

The default settings are "capping" the framerate to 60, but it seems you can "unlock" the cap by deselecting the "use frame rate" checkbox under render > system properties tab:
[image]

Comment: I am quite confused: after this is done, my fps is still at ~59/60. It would occasionally go above 60 but *immediately* cap to 59.9. I kept lowering settings to make sure that there wasn't a coincidence of me just running at 60 constantly, but this is not the case. Do I have to do this over *all* my scenes? What could I do do try to make this work? I appreciate the answer, but I would like a little more info so mine would also work.

Comment: Generally speaking this is not a good way to get a higher frame rate. It will uncouple the game-time from wall-time, so on faster computers the game will appear faster, and on slower computers game will appear slower. It's better to use the FPS option under World settings.